# python read date and time from csv

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, series

my data looks like that:

```
GIdx,Date,num,Time
1,11/28/2012,20,10:05:50
1,11/28/2012,20,10:05:50
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:24
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:24
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:25
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:25
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:26
3,11/28/2012,20,10:09:34
3,11/28/2012,20,10:09:34
```

i try to read column **Date** as `datetime` and column **Time**  as `time`
but when I check the their type I get `Series`:

```
type(df['Date'])

class pandas.core.series.Series

type(df_original['Time'])

class pandas.core.series.Series
```

I did something like:

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename,sep=",", header = 0, na_values=['NA'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter `parse_dates` with columns where are `dates` and `times`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""GIdx,Date,num,Time
1,11/28/2012,20,10:05:50
1,11/28/2012,20,10:05:50
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:24
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:24
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:25
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:25
2,11/28/2012,20,10:09:26
3,11/28/2012,20,10:09:34
3,11/28/2012,20,10:09:34"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])


print (df)
            Date_Time  GIdx  num
0 2012-11-28 10:05:50     1   20
1 2012-11-28 10:05:50     1   20
2 2012-11-28 10:09:24     2   20
3 2012-11-28 10:09:24     2   20
4 2012-11-28 10:09:25     2   20
5 2012-11-28 10:09:25     2   20
6 2012-11-28 10:09:26     2   20
7 2012-11-28 10:09:34     3   20
8 2012-11-28 10:09:34     3   20

print (df.dtypes)
Date_Time    datetime64[ns]
GIdx                  int64
num                   int64
dtype: object
```

You can omit parameters `sep=","`, `header = 0` and `na_values=['NA']`, because there are by default:

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename,sep=",", header = 0, na_values=['NA'])


df=pd.read_csv(filename)
```